# Как сверстать шестиугольники с текстом?

Tags: html, css

Собственно вопрос, как сверстать такие объекты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что это hexagon, но как разместить подобным образом цифру и картинку - нет.

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: #47a759;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 86.60px solid #47a759;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 86.60px solid #47a759;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Comment: у вас есть хоть намек на код? или вы хотите готовое решение?

Comment: Отредактировал пост. Не знаю, как реализовать... там одна сторона ещё другим цветом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
div.test {
  xwidth: 100%;
  xperspective: 750px;
  height: 200px;
}

  
.cube {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #85cd66;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
  
.front {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) translateZ(50px);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.right {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(32deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(-148deg) translateZ(50px);
}

/* cuboid - 100 x 100 x 200 */
.cuboid .front {
  width: 200px;
}

.cuboid .top {
  width: 200px;
}

.cuboid .right {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(122deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.cuboid .back {
  width: 200px;
}

.cuboid .bottom {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
  
<div class="test test1">
  <h1></h1>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front">
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-wrench "></i> 1
    </div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side top">1.</div>
    <div class="side bottom">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: картинки я так понимаю это иконки, сейчас попробую добавить